# Form with different target urls to send the POST to

Tags: html, django, forms, django-forms

I have one view displaying a form. Now, depending on the button the user chooses, I want to have the data processed in a different way. These "different ways" correspond with different views that I want the POST request go to.

Please help me building a form with multiple buttons leading to different urls/views.

```html
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Process form with view ONE">
    <input type="submit" value="Process form with view TWO">
    <input type="submit" value="Process form with view THREE">
</form>
```

My problem here is that the action attribute of the form tag defines where this POST request is going to. How can I change that target url via multiple buttons?

I know I could also handle this logic on the server-side. But the question is: Do I **have to**? If not, please show me the way

Answer (score 1):

you can use ajax with `onclick` attribute. `post_url` as an argument like this

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Process form with view ONE" onclick='testFun(url_one)'>
    <input type="submit" value="Process form with view TWO" onclick='testFun(url_two)'>
    <input type="submit" value="Process form with view THREE" onclick='testFun(url_three)'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle this on the **frontend** without even using `ajax`, you can use `JavaScript` to change the `action` URL of the form based on which button is clicked before submitting the form.

Slight change on your HTML code

```html
<form method="post" id="my-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" id="view1" value="Process form with view ONE">
    <input type="submit" id="view2" value="Process form with view TWO">
    <input type="submit" id="view3" value="Process form with view THREE">
</form>
```

JavaScript for handling the redirection of the form based the button clicked

```js
const form = document.getElementById('my-form');
const button1 = document.getElementById('view1');
const button2 = document.getElementById('view2');
const button3 = document.getElementById('view3');

button1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  form.action = '/view1/';
});

button2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  form.action = '/view2/';
});

button3.addEventListener('click', () => {
  form.action = '/view3/';
});

// Submit the form
form.submit();
```

**Note**: You can use jQuery for better code optimization